# split an encrypted data into 3 pats in php

Tags: php

I wish to get the phpcode for split an encrypted data into `3` equal parts.
For example:

```
Q5vRFsC+6Rs08JlvWDMc/sqwR6MpPTzO/p6UH+bPDBE=
```

I want this data should be divided into three equal parts and stored it in three variables.

Pls help me.

Comment: First question: why? Second, you can use `substr` for that.

Comment: Not possible. 44 / 3 = 14.6......

Comment: kudos for you being honest, but this is not a "I wish code" plattform. Show some effort.

Comment: Might be the point to note here is divide into  3 "Equal" parts. @BartFriederichs  your question "why" is inappropriate, nobody knows how a programer thinks , so its wise to just answer the question. Knowing entire logic may be useful for giving a better answer but sometimes its harder explain everything here. Hence I think the question is correct and precise.

Comment: @ClainDsilva I beg to differ, knowing the "why" often gives better insights and better solutions. I understand that not always all implications of the "why" can be given or explained, but if they can, we can probably give a better answer and make the OP a better coder. Read this meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and this link: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @BartFriederichs you point is already accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "Q5vRFsC+6Rs08JlvWDMc/sqwR6MpPTzO/p6UH+bPDBE=";
$parts = str_split($str, strlen($str)/3+1);
print_r($parts);
```

Comment: That added some insights to the dividing problem but am explanation to the logic for 3+1 will be much appreciated.